# How does different versions work on the marketplace?

Tags: android, version, apk, google-play

I have completed my starter app for google play market. I would like to make a free and paid version, so what im wondering is:

Can I comment out the parts in the paid version for the free version and put in dialogs referencing the paid on the marketplace more specificly using the same project just different version numbers and exported apk's?

Im wondering because i heard the marketplace will not let an apk have the same package name but ive used apps before that if you have the paid version you cannot have the free version, so im guessing its all about the version#

thank you for your time

Comment: You're better off with a single code base and compiling it as an OSS or pro version, or having a single version that requires a license key. Simply commenting out chunks of code before compiling any project is poor practice.

Comment: i dont know how to go about doing this, i wana get it right you know, i finished the paid, i know how to get the free done, just how to export, different package names? version numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that Google Play does not allow APK's with the same package name's to be uploaded. It is using the package name that the Play store differentiates different apps from other apps.

You are, however, a little off track in thinking that it is the version that takes care of same app (free and paid).

However (again) Free and Paid version of the same apps can co-exist on the same device downloaded with the same Google account. There may be a function in the apps which checks and informs the user. But that is not a mechanism provided by the Google Play store.

Take for example an app called FriendCaster. (*I am an independent freelancer who has nothing to do with FriendCaster or OneLouder Apps*)

1. The free version of FriendCaster is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.blueNotifyFree
2. The paid version if the same app is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.blueNotify

They both have the same versions expect with different package names (the endings are different). And you will be able to install both the apps simultaneously on one device.

In my case, I use the identical code base for both the free and the paid versions of my app. The only difference is (obviously) the paid version has all the advertisements stripped out from the XML's.

I use two different Eclipse work-spaces to keep my free and paid version separate from each other. This is more for convenience than any thing else. You can very well have the two projects in the same Eclipse work-space.

However, going by your comment on the OP, you cannot export two different APK's with different package names using the same project. If you have finished your paid version, you will need to create a new project for the free version. And you will need to export APK's of each project independently.

To keep parity in the code bases, I avoid using hard code wherever possible. For instance, in an Activity that opens the app's Google Play details page, instead of hard coding my package name in it, I use something like this:

```
Uri playUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + Feedback.this.getPackageName());
Intent openGooglePlay = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, playUri);
try {
    startActivity(openGooglePlay);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    // SHOW A TOAST
    String tstMessage = "Could not launch the Play Store app.";
    showToast.showToast(tstMessage);
}
```

I hope I have made some sense with this post. If you need any clarifications, feel free to ask away. :-)

Comment: @JRowan: Awesome. Glad I could help. And good luck with your apps forthcoming launch. :-)